# Goal: 10 Altruist badges

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Currently we have only [FIVE altruist badges](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges/48/altruist) earned on Expats! This is such a shame - it's an easy way to earn a badge.  I'm going to create an answer below listing for posterity the first 10 people ever to earn the Altruist badges.  If you'd like to make this list, start placing some bounties! If you don't have enough rep, start answering some bountied questions!

Comment: You're doing a good job promoting this beta site. I really hope to see Expats graduate soon. May I ask what's the requirement for graduating? I swear I have seen it before but I can't find it now.

Comment: @DipenShah the meaning and requirements of *graduation* has changed over the past few years. I think [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) is the most up to date rules, but SE has also introduced https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905/design-independent-graduation-is-on-for-early-september?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

## **[First 10 Altruists on Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges/48/altruist)**

1. April 2, 2014 - Mark Mayo
2. May 27, 2014 - Karlson
3. August 30, 2017 - Dipen Shah
4. Sep 7, 2017 - SztupY
5. April 1, 2018 - jpatokal
6. ?
7. ?
8. ?
9. ?
10. ?

Place a bounty now to join this list!